# How to create a better object

Tags: java, arrays, list, oop

Related to my previous thread, i want to print an output like this:

```
bookId = "1234" (String)
bookName = "Machine Learning" (String)
price = $20 (int)
ratings = (array of object)
rater = a, score = 5
rater = b, score = 3
```

But this time, i tried to use an OOP manner.

So first, i made a POJO class called `ProductView`, the class will be look like this:

```
public class ProductView {

    // field
    private String bookId;
    private String bookName;
    private int price;
    private List<Ratings> ratings;

    // a constructor i tried to make
    public ProductView(String bookId, String bookName, int price, List<Ratings> ratings) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
    this.bookName = bookName;
    this.price = price;
    this.ratings = ratings;
    }

    public String getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(String bookId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
    this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Ratings getRatings() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRatings(Ratings ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }
}
```

After that, i made a class called `Ratings` with the following field:

```
public class Ratings {

    private String rater;
    private int score;

    public Ratings(String rater, int score) {
        this.rater = rater;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And finally, i made a Main Class called `Main`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

In the Main Class, i want to create an instance of the ProductView class and give it some value.

But i don't know how to do it with a list object param in my constructor.

Anyone can give me some insight?

Comment: that was my problem actually, how can i define a value in my object since my constructor has a list<object>?

Comment: To begin with, your ratings getter and setter won't work because those methods deal with `Ratings` but your field is actually a `List<Ratings>`. Secondly, I think class `Ratings` should be called `Rating` because there's only one rating value per object. Once you fix those issues, create a list of ratings using `List<Rating> ratings = java.util.Arrays.asList(new Rating(...), new Rating(...), ...);`

Comment: thanks, it really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first:

List is an interface, you should pass an implementation of list such as ArrayList or similar

second:

you have a compilation error in ProductView -> SetBookId, in this.itemId you don't have itemId as member or constructor parameter

furthermore, in get/set rating you need to pass and return list of Ratings.

nameing:
Ratings is actually just a Rating, you can make a new class of List or just use the Rating as is but change the name

now for your Question: 
you can initialize first the list with objects and then send it to the constructor
such as:

```
    List<Ratings> ratings = new ArrayList<>();
    ratings.add(new Ratings("rater",5));
    ratings.add(new Ratings("rater2",6));

    ProductView productView = new ProductView("bookId","bookName",1,ratings);
```

Or, just initialize the ArrayList in the Constructor, the first way is preferable:

```
    ProductView productView1 = new ProductView("bookId","bookName",1,
            new ArrayList<Ratings>(Arrays.asList(new Ratings("rater",5), new Ratings("rater2",6))
    ));
```

hopefully, this answers your question

same as  DodgyCodeException mentioned in the comments.

Comment: yes, this is what i was looking for.
thanks for your help.

Comment: @fajri, if this was helpful, please add ranking in the question.

Comment: i'm sorry, how to add ranking in the question?